# How to hide Azure Function URL?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime

So I just created an Azure Function that is triggered by Azure Blob Storage upload. There is no HTTP trigger.

- Why does this app have a PUBLIC-FACING URL?
- How do I disable it?
- Is there any kind of security mitigation needed?

`https://fa06192020test8.azurewebsites.net` (deleting soon, so hit it now!)

I don't want anything visible to the outside world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's the standard welcome page for Azure Functions
- You can disable it by setting `AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage` app setting value to `true`. However, you will still see a response when you hit the URL on the browser.
- From a web perspective: not really. However, you always need to store your connection string in a secure place. For example, you shouldn't store your blob storage connection string in json file in your code. Obviously it's so hard to penetrate your FTP and get your JSON file, but still not secure. You can use Azure portal to set environment variables for the connection string. But still not the securest. You can have a look to the `Azure KeyVault` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/ and `Managed Service Identity` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview if you really really want to build secure Azure Functions on your high-level ops (Let's say you're parsing some `government, PCI, PHI, PII` data)

Since it's only Azure Blob Trigger Azure Functions, if you don't expose your azure functions URL to the Internet, nobody would predict your Azure Functions URL. Even if they predict, the above mentioned things would be still applied. So don't worry! :)

P.S. You can't (and also shouldn't) hide/remove the .azurewebsites.net URL. It's using everywhere. From deploying your code to the health checks. It's everywhere. Also, you should create HealthChecks via Application Insights as well to check whether your function is health or not.

Comment: Excellent answer @Mehmet. Thank you. I am indeed using KeyVault with a system-assigned managed identity to secure secrets. Will add the `AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage` app setting you mentioned.

Comment: Just adding on here... from a tin foil hat perspective, one should be careful with their Function App naming convention. The name and potentially its status (up/down) are publically visible at all times.

Comment: You are welcome mate - I'm glad it helped  @SeaDude

Answer (score 0):

One more option to make it more secure though would be to block all incoming IP addresses in Networking Tab: [image]

Add a role in Access Restrictions (e.g. Deny All for 0.0.0.0/0 -> meaning Deny All) and then anyone hitting the side will see the following: [image]

More Info on this can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions

its for App Services, but concepts are same.